# Reordenar colunas em um gráfico de colunas empilhadas de acordo com um nível específico

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

Suponha que eu tenho o gráfico abaixo:

```r
library(tidyverse)

mpg %>%
  group_by(class, drv) %>%
  count() %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = class, y = n, fill = drv)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Eu gostaria que as colunas estivessem ordenadas pelo nível `4` da variável `drv`. À esquerda estariam os maiores valores de `drv` e esses valores iriam decaindo até o mínimo. Nesse caso, a ordem desejada para a variável categórica no eixo x, da esquerda para a direita, é `suv`, `pickup`, `compact`, `subcompact`, `midsize`, `minivan` e `2seater` (embora a ordem das duas últimas posições não importe, pois não há ocorrência de `4` entre elas).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pode-se usar a função `interaction` para criar um factor misto de contagens e `drv`. Depois reordena-se a classe tendo em conta máximos deste factor.

E ainda,

- `count` agrupa e conta, não são necessárias duas instruções;
- a seguir a reordenar a classe pode-se deixar cair a variável temporária, `select(-.x)`;
- talvez `rank` seja logicamente preferível a `as.integer`, neste caso os resultados são iguais.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(tidyverse))

mpg %>%
  mutate(drv = factor(drv, levels = c("f", "r", "4"))) %>%
  count(class, drv) %>% 
  mutate(
    .x = as.integer(interaction(n, drv)),
    class = fct_reorder(class, .x = .x, .fun = max, .desc = TRUE)
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = class, y = n, fill = drv)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>